# How to remove logo by copy/paste shape from side of the object?

Tags: workflow, 3d-printing

I want to print a golden ball cup from sketchfab for my little bro, but I have trouble removing the logo.
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/golden-ball-award-bce02dc608e04827b11ab9aa26316cc6

So my thought to remove the logo was just to remove the mesh then copy the side without the logo on it. I wanted to simply separate the mesh, duplicate the mesh, move the duplicated mesh then join.

But I struggle at the moving part.
How can I do it? Is there a better way to do what I want?

edit:

[The file](https://easyupload.io/fiwsa6)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can either extrude and try to recreate the same shape, or select another (maybe the opposite), duplicate and paste it here, hard to tell without the object. Maybe share it if it's copyright free?

Comment: "select another (maybe the opposite), duplicate and paste it here" that's what I want to do, but I struggle at moving the duplicated mesh to the right place. I added the file link.

Comment: I [couldn't resist](https://pasteall.org/blend/27ba4915b1904b06958790c2476f3b19).  For me, the symmetry turned out to be: dupe of antipodean face, rotated in Global Z about  center of top face by 180, then the island rotated in its own Normal Z about its own center by 180.

Answer (score 5):

To easily remove the part with the logo you could select a closed loop around it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>clicks (shortest path), then <kbd>H</kbd> hiding it, then hovering on the part that is not the logo, pressing <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd> to hide it as well, then select everything remaining and remove it (<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>), and reveal the old geometry with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>. The reason I hide the rest before deleting is to be sure the logo is deleted even if it's not linked geometry.

[image]

To transplant the hole with another side, select another side (I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> to *Select More*), <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> *Duplicate*, <kbd>.</kbd> and choose *3D Cursor* pivot, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> to mirror across the 3D cursor (you can limit to an axis but probably not necessary), <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> to *Merge by Distance*, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to *Recalculate Normals*.

[image]

If the shape is not symmetric - the opposite of a face is an edge or pole, you can just rotate the duplicated part by a reciprocal of the number of sides on the given row. So in my case, because there's 10 sides, I rotate by $1\over10$ of a circle, or by ${360°\over10} = 36°$ around Z. Then I realize, faces alternate and neighbors aren't the same, so I select a neighbor of the neighbor, and rotate it by $36°\times2 = 72°$:

[image]

Remember to also set the pivot to 3D cursor and remove doubles, but you don't have to recalculate normals this time.

Comment: that's nice, I learned a lot thank you

Answer (score 5):

Hard to do it with a symmetrize operation, what you can do is simply duplicate another face:

Cut off the face with the logo, select this other one:

[image]

Choose the top view, move the selection, rotate it (you can calculate the rotation angle as Markus von Broady explains, as you have 10 faces all around you need to rotate it 2 x (360/10)), align it with the hole as much as possible:

[image]

Keep the selection, also select the edge of the hole, merge by distance, play with the threshold in the *Operator* box until the vertices merge:

[image]

You're good:

[image]

Comment: Thank a lot, I will do so